# How to make the text box grow till the width of its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="mail-holder">
  <ul class="multi-input">
    <li class="temp-value">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="mail-input">
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="button-holder">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Share Users</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
   </div>
</div>

.mail-holder
{
    margin: 0px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}
.temp-value
{
    width: auto;
    min-width: 90px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.mail-input
{
    outline:none !important;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top:2px;
    resize:none;
    background: none;
}
.button-holder
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
.button-holder .btn-cancel
{
    color: #7d7d7d;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
.multi-input
{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #83a3b8;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 80px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.temp-li
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    background-color: #def2ff;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bfd7e7;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".mail-input").keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $(".mail-input").val();

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            if (value.length == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $('.multi-input li.temp-value').before('<li class="temp-li">' + value + '<span class="close-btn">x</span></li>');
                $('.mail-input').val('').focus();
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == 8) {

            if (value.length == 0) {
                $('.multi-input li:last-child').prev().remove();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
$('.btn-cancel').click(function () {
    $('.auto-gen li').remove();
    $('.multi-input li').not('li:last').remove();
    $('.mail-input').val('').focus();
});
$('body').on('click', '.close-btn', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I need the text box to expand till the end of my parent div's width. Once the value of the text overflows the width of the parent. It should breakdown to the next line. All I done till is just like input tag which helps to store the value of the input and stored in the li. Thanks in advance.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DK6p4/)

Comment: By text box you mean input right ? If so you can't break lines in a input of type=text, you should better user <textarea> if you want to break lines

Comment: yep its working fine but i need the text box to grow till the end of the parent div and break the text down whereas here it will do grow it hold a certain width i dont know whats wrong with ma code.

Comment: i dnt want to break the text box actually i need to break down the list which holds the text box

Comment: I wrote a plugin for this, maybe you can get some ideas from it. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GQyB8/1/

Comment: Use `width:100%;` for the textbox

Comment: i tried width 100% whereas when i started typing next tag the input breaks down to the next line automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am giving the solution for the full width of textbox. I am not sure about the break down the list.

```
.temp-value
{
width: auto;
min-width: 90px;
max-width: 100%;
height: 26px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
.mail-input
{
outline:none !important;
border: none;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-top:2px;
resize:none;
background: none;
width:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DK6p4/1/)

Comment: Could u check the demo after entering a tag. The input will break down to next line i don't want it to be like that.

Comment: which tag? can you give the fiddle link including the tag?

Comment: type some text and press enter in the text box it will have. It will have tag which u entered. And start typing next text it will start from next line I dont need that. I need to it start next after the first tag and continue till the width of the parent div